# MultiList icon_URLImage

Tags: codenameone

Hope you are doing well, 
I tried icon_URLImage to optimize the loading in multilist below my code

```
   while (c.next()) 
   {
         hlist = new Hashtable();
         r = c.getRow();
         hlist.put("Line1", r.getString(6));
         hlist.put("Line2", r.getString(8));
         sb.delete(0, sb.length());
         sb.append("alb").append(r.getInteger(4));
         urlcover = r.getString(10); 
         hlist.put("icon", defaultimg);
         hlist.put("iconName", sb.toString());
         hlist.put("icon_URLImage", urlcover);
         vlist.add(hlist);
    } 
    mlist.setModel(new Model(vlist));
   mlist.setRenderer(createListRenderer());

 In createListRenderer my code is :
 private static MultiButton createRendererMultiButton() {
    MultiButton b = new MultiButton();
    b.setName("icon");
    b.setNameLine1("Line1");
    b.setNameLine2("Line2");
    b.setUIID("Label");
    return b;
}

private static ListCellRenderer createListRenderer() {
    MultiButton sel = createRendererMultiButton();
    MultiButton unsel = createRendererMultiButton();
    return new GenericListCellRenderer(sel, unsel);
}
```

PlaceHolder is loaded, but online image still not display, please help me.
My english is not good so excuse me.

Comment: According Mr. Shai Almog I change **`b.setName("icon");`** to **`b.setIconName("icon");`** but still not working, placeholder is not update by online image

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the line:

```
hlist.put("icon", defaultimg);
```

You are placing an image there and the URLImage code thinks the download was already completed.

FYI This isn't a `MultiList` its a list of `MultiButton`'s